# Horizonzal and vertical alignment with CSS

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering

I need to make a header in HTML/CSS that should look like this:

[image]

There are 3 sections containind different elements, always both vertically und horizontally centered.
The middle section should be able to receive arbitrary number of images. Depending on user actions, new images will be added.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And what have you tried? Show us your code of what so far you've done.

Comment: This looks like a WebMasters.SE question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle for you:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table">
    <td id="left"> < Back</td>
    <td id="middle"></td>
    <td id="right"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTx_UltN7oNiHFwk7-pGEkunHaXz8Nk3o3-eKNUHzktoZuM-BT7Pg" /></td>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .table
{
    width:100%;
    height:88px;
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#left
{
    width:100px;
    height:88px;
        border:1px solid black;
}

#middle
{
    width:auto;
    height:88px;
        border:1px solid black;
}

#middle img
{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
}

#right
{
    width:100px;
    height:88px;
        border:1px solid black;
}
```

**JS:**

```
    document.getElementById("middle").innerHTML += '<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTx_UltN7oNiHFwk7-pGEkunHaXz8Nk3o3-eKNUHzktoZuM-BT7Pg" />' ;
document.getElementById("middle").innerHTML += '<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTx_UltN7oNiHFwk7-pGEkunHaXz8Nk3o3-eKNUHzktoZuM-BT7Pg" />' ; // and so on....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Lj5/2/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table for construction that layout button all mordern web not using the table instead you can use div and change the display property corresponding to table layout like bellow

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table">
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell1">&lt;Button</div>
    <div class="cell2">
        <img src="http://donaldmurrayexpat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Cool-2.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://donaldmurrayexpat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Cool-2.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://donaldmurrayexpat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Cool-2.jpg"/>
        <img src="http://donaldmurrayexpat.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Cool-2.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="cell3">&lt;Button</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table{
width:"100%";
border: 1px solid;
}
img{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
.row{
display:table-row;
width:100%;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
}
.cell1{
display:table-cell;
    height:20px;
     vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding:20px;
}
.cell2{
display:table-cell;
    height:20px;
     vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding:20px;
    width:100%;
}
.cell3{
display:table-cell;
    height:20px;
     vertical-align:middle;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding:20px;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5JDgk/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I have a soultion without table, only with divs: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsrufus/3gy5g/1/)

The vertical-alignment must be done with padding... but i think this is a great start.

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="left_header"><p>< back</p></div>
  <div id="middle_header">img img img</div>
  <div id="right_header"><p>image</p></div> 
</div>
```

And here the CSS:

```
#header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 88px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #header div {
        float: left;
    }
    #left_header {
        width: 100px;
        height: 88px;
        background-color: green;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #right_header {
        width: 100px;
        height: 88px;
        background-color: green;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
    #middle_header {
        width: calc(100% - 200px);
        height: 88px;
        background-color: yellow;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Code here, Dynamic code

http://jsfiddle.net/jeyashri_shri/q5z4B/7/

HTML:

```
 <table border="1" width="100%" height="50%">
 <tr >
 <td>Left</td>
 <td>
 <img src=""/>
 <img src=""/>
 <img src=""/>
 <img src=""/>
 </td>
 <td>Right</td>
 </tr>
```

CSS:

```
 table td{border-left:0;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;text-align:center;}
 table td:nth-child(1){width:100px;}
 table td:nth-child(3){border-right:0;width:100px;}  
 td img{width:50px;height:50px;display:inline}
```